# Schedulers.io() Throwing NullPointerException in my Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I'm trying to create **unit tests** for the method of my ViewModel below, which uses **RxJava/RxKotlin**.

```
fun doLogin(address: String, serial: String) {
    mLoading.value = true
    mCompositeDisposable.add(
        mRepository
            .doLogin(address, createJsonArray(serial, generatePinJSON()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                onSuccess = { json ->
                    /** CODE **/
                },
                onError = { error ->
                    /** CODE **/
                }
            )
    )
}
```

But when **Schedulers.io()** is invoked in the test method, it throws a NullPointerException.

**I've tried to use this approaches below:**

https://medium.com/@dbottillo/how-to-unit-test-your-rxjava-code-in-kotlin-d239364687c9 (Creating a Rule)

https://medium.com/@PaulinaSadowska/writing-unit-tests-on-asynchronous-events-with-rxjava-and-rxkotlin-1616a27f69aa (Passing Schedulers to ViewModel)

In both approaches, it says to use **Schedulers.trampoline()** in test method. But it still throwing the error.

I'm running out of options, couldn't figure out why this happening.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, you got null because you have not mocked `mRepository.doLogin`. Try adding this at the beginning of your test function

```
whenever(mRepository.doLogin).thenReturn(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I've mocked with `Mockito.`when`(mRepository.doLogin("", "")).thenReturn(Single.just(""))`

Comment: Oh, I've found the problem. You were right, I was mocking the mRepository.doLogin wrong.

Comment: Just for clarification: In the posted code above has a method called createJsonArray. If the parameters of the mRepository.doLogin are empty, it creates a "[]" String. So instead of mocking the two paremeters with "", I needed to pass the second parameter as "[]". Something like this `Mockito.when(mRepository.doLogin("", "[]")).thenReturn(Single.just(""))` and it works.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Learn to read stacktraces, it's easy and it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Hi bach , i faced with this problem and i added `Momckito.when` before please check my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192492/test-junit-rxjava-method