# Junit test Rxjava method

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, rx-java

I tested the `Rxjava` methods many times without **problem** but now i faced with this **problem** :
**`Null pointer exception` in this `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` line.**

```
 fun registerPhone(phoneNumber: String, nationalId: String) {
        val disposable =
            mRepository.getRegister(jsonObjectToRequestBody(phoneNumber, nationalId))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //NPE in this line
.
.
.
}
```

**I used `Mockito` `when` before it but i dont know why this problem cause until now and this is my `test` method :**

```
class ViewModelTest : BaseTest() {
    private val mResponseBody = ResponseBody.create(
        null, ""
    )
    private var mGson= Gson()
    private val mRequestBody = RequestBody.create(null, mGson.toJson(Register("123", "123")))
    .
    .
    .

    @Test
    fun registerPhone_success() {
        Mockito.`when`(mRepository.getRegister(mRequestBody)).thenReturn(
            Single.just(
                Response.success(mResponseBody)
            )
        )
        mViewModel.registerPhone("123", "123")
}
}
```

This is my `base test` :

```
open class BaseTest {
    @Before
    fun setUpClass() {
        RxJavaPlugins.reset()
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
        val immediate = object : Scheduler() {
            override fun scheduleDirect(run: Runnable, delay: Long, unit: TimeUnit): Disposable {

                return super.scheduleDirect(run, 0, unit)
            }

            override fun createWorker(): Worker {
                return ExecutorScheduler.ExecutorWorker(Executor { it.run() }, true)
            }
        }
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> immediate }
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> immediate }
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> immediate }
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> immediate }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> immediate }

        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDownClass() {
        RxJavaPlugins.reset()
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are testing this in wrong way. Try this:

```
class ViewModelTest : BaseTest() {
    private val mResponseBody = ResponseBody.create(
        null, ""
    )
    private var mGson= Gson()

    private val mRepository = mock()


    @Test
    fun registerPhone_success() {
        whenever(mRepository.getRegister(any())).thenReturn(
            Single.just(
                Response.success(mResponseBody)
            )
        )
        mViewModel.registerPhone("123", "123")
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i faced with this : `any() must not be null`

Comment: are you using `import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.any`

Comment: No i didnt use it

Comment: please use that and try again

Comment: OMG, it works but how ?what was the problem?can you explain more please?

Comment: I used that codes in another project and it works fine but in that project i did not have `request body` it was simple object.

Comment: This `RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> immediate }` did not work?!! or `Mockito.when` did not work but i tested it and it worked as well

Comment: I think this `private val mRequestBody = RequestBody.create(null, mGson.toJson(Register("123", "123")))` line has difference treatment.

Comment: Exactly this requestbody was the issue. Since you testing the logic you can just pass any() here.